# NSHTTPCookieStorage Vs keychain vs NSUserdefault

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsuserdefaults, keychain, nshttpcookie

iOS : `NSHTTPCookieStorage`, `Keychain`, `NSUserDefault` between these three, what is the best place to store token on device? and why?

Note: I don't want to share token with any other app or Safari/browser.

Answer (score 1):

`NSUserDefault`, data stored in the it will remain as it is till the application is there. Once you delete the application everything will be lost. Not fully secured.

`Keychain`, data stored in it will remain as it till the user reset the entire phone settings. Refer this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH208-SW3) for more info along with implementation. If user do backup of that iPhone & re-store any other phone with it all data will be available to that device. Also all the data are stored securely & in encrypted format.

`NSHTTPCookieStorage` implements a singleton object (shared instance) that manages storage of cookies. Each cookie is represented by an instance of the NSHTTPCookie class. As a rule, cookies are shared among all applications and are kept in sync across process boundaries. Session cookies (where the cookie object’s isSessionOnly method returns YEStrue) are local to a single process and are not shared.

If you would like to store token use in Application as well as in Safari browser or in any other app then `NSHTTPCookieStorage` is better option for you.

Comment: But  I don't want to share token with any other app or Safari/browser.

Comment: Then Keychain is best way for you.

Comment: If you would like to update you token as an when user login then NSUserDefault is good.

Comment: If you want to secure the toke is the keychain. `NSUserDefault` is almost never a good choice and is not secure.